# Simple PHP form to MySQL not working, maybe inaccuracy with the table?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

The following code is made by [this](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-processing.html) tutorial. The database structure is here: http://www.shareimages.com/image.php?62275-pJqgl5ejk6Col5yVnaY-local_mysql_screen.gif

If i try insert data to the more simple "member" table, the code is well-functioning, but not with the "user" table. I can't figure out the obstruction in this case. please recommend some solutions.

```php
<?php
function PrepSQL($value)
{
    // Stripslashes
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    // Quote
    $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    return($value);
}

    if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {

        $company=$_POST['company'];
        $vat=$_POST['vat'];
        $city=$_POST['city'];
        $zip=$_POST['zip'];
        $str=$_POST['str'];
        $nr=$_POST['nr'];
        $other=$_POST['other'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $tel=$_POST['tel'];
        $url=$_POST['url'];

        $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'asd', 'asdpass');
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db("fc" ,$db);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO member (company,vat,city,zip,str,nr,other,email,tel,url) VALUES (".
                 PrepSQL($company) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($vat) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($city) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($zip) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($str) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($nr) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($other) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($email) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($tel) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($url) . ")";

        mysql_query($sql);
        echo "data saved";
    }
?>
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST" >
    <input name="company" type="text" id="company" class="text required" placeholder="Cégnév" />
    <input name="vat" type="text" id="vat" class="text " placeholder="Adószám" />
    <fieldset>
    <select name="city" id="city" class="item select city r4 required " title="Település kiválasztása" placeholder="Település"  />
        <option value="31353">Aba</option><option value="16547">Abádszalók</option>
    </select>
    <input name="zip" type="text" id="zip" class="text required" placeholder="isz." />
    <input name="str" type="text" id="str" class="text required" placeholder="közterület neve" />
    <input name="nr" type="text" id="nr" class="text required" placeholder="szám" />
    <input name="other" type="text" id="other" class="text " placeholder="egyéb" />
    <input name="email" type="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" id="email" class="text required" placeholder="email" value="@" />
    <input name="tel" type="tel" pattern="[\+]\d{2}[\ ]\d{2}[\ ]\d{4}\d{3}" id="tel" class="text required" value="+36 " title="Telefonszám: +36 00 1234567"  placeholder="+36 00 1234567" />
    <input name="url" type="url" id="url" class="text " value="http://" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Adatok elküldése" class="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: please use `if(!mysql_query($sql)) { echo (mysql_error()); } `(hopefully mysql_error() is the right one, my memory is a bit shaky in php/mysql nowadays). This will give you the error the mysql service is providing, which should point straight foward to your problem

Comment: Also, maybe action="#" should point to a relative/full page path, even if it is sending the data via POST to the same page, like so action="somePageName.php".

Comment: Try replacing `mysql_query($sql);` with `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` to see if that shows any error message

Comment: You can try to echo the $query in your page. Copy and paste it in something like PhpMyAdmin to get a good description of your problem. Hope it helps!

Comment: Indeed, best way is just to check query if that is correct by echoing it and copy it in phpmyadmin or simular program. You will know inmideatly if the query is correct.

Comment: thank you.. finally Najzero solved the problem: sending "tel", waiting for "phone" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a flaw in your insert statement. The given columns do not match your db columns.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO member (company,vat,city,zip,str,nr,other,email,tel,url)
```

Change 'tel' to 'phone' and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it the table 'user' instead of 'member' in your SQL Query?

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO user (company,vat,city,zip,str,nr,other,email,tel,url) VALUES (".
                 PrepSQL($company) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($vat) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($city) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($zip) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($str) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($nr) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($other) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($email) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($tel) . ", " .
                 PrepSQL($url) . ")";
```

Comment: oh yes.. but changing this to user don't solve the probelm :(

Comment: Have you tried this already? You can try to echo the $query in your page. Copy and paste it in something like PhpMyAdmin to get a good description of your problem. Hope it helps!